# Mocking (file.exists() && file.isDirectory() java

Tags: java, mockito, junit4

I have a java method checking File Existence..

```
public String checkFileExistance(String arg) throws IOException {

String FolderPath = SomePath

File file = new File(FolderPath);

if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory()) {

//Do something here

}
}
```

i want to mock the file.exist() and file.isDirectory() to make it return **true** always

i tried  below method:

```
public void test_checkFileExistance1() throws IOException {

/**Mock*/

File mockedFile = Mockito.mock(File.class);
Mockito.when(mockedFile.exists()).thenReturn(true);
Mockito.when(mockedFile.isDirectory()).thenReturn(true);


/**Actual Call*/
ProcessClass.checkFileExistance("arg");
}
```

but it always returns **false**

Comment: You are not calling `exists()` and `isDirectory()` on the mocked object. Instead, you create a `new File(..)` object.

Comment: i am not clear can you elaborate ?

Answer (score 1):

You create a mock object `mockedFile` in your test method. But this mock object is not used within your `checkExistance()` method. This is because you create another File object and call the `exists()` and `isDirectory()` methods on this newly created (and *not* mocked object).

If your `checkExistance()` method would take a file object as parameter instead of the name of the file, you could pass the mocked object to the method and it would work as expected:

```
public String checkFileExistance(File file) throws IOException {
    if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory()) {
        // do something here
    }
}

public void test_checkFileExistance1() throws IOException {
    File mockedFile = Mockito.mock(File.class);
    Mockito.when(mockedFile.exists()).thenReturn(true);
    Mockito.when(mockedFile.isDirectory()).thenReturn(true);

    /**Actual Call*/
    ProcessClass.checkFileExistance(mockedFile);
}
```

Comment: Sadly I am a tester and can not change the checkFileExistance method created by developer. I am only allowed to write Junit test cases in my organization. is there any other alternate solution ?

Comment: You can try to mock the `ProcessClass.checkFileExistance(String)` method to return `true` when it is called.

Comment: the actual method is bigger i trimmed it for better understanding. actually, checkFileExistance is getting folderpath from some other method from other class and checking if the file exists or not. once the file.exists is found true it will be used for further operation, its not a simple true false returning method.

Answer (score 1):

You mock a `File`, but that is not the one that is used in your class.  In your class you call `new File(...)` which returns a *real* `File` `Object`; not the one you've prepared.

You can use PowerMockito to do this.

Something along the lines of:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(TheClassWithTheCheckFileExistanceMethod.class)
public class TheTest {

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        final File mockFile = mock(File.class);
        Mockito.doReturn(true).when(mockFile).exists();
        // Whatever other mockery you need.

        PowerMockito.whenNew(File.class).withAnyArguments()
                .thenReturn(mockFile);
    }
}
```

will do this.